# Remove duplicate elements from the list in list assignments in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

In this part of our code, we want to create a list from the order dataframe and from our other list, with products that comply with our constrains. Since there are too many loops in our code, there are many duplicated products. We have created two def functions to eliminate this problem, but it don't work correctly. What should we do so that the products in the lists don't repeat?

This is the assignment part of our code.

````
routeList= list()

def routeListControl(assigned_products):
    deger = False
    for i in routeList:
        if (i.getOrderNo() == assigned_products.getOrderNo()):
            deger = True
            if (i.getItemNo() != assigned_products.getItemNo()):
                deger = False
    if (deger == False):
        routeList.append(assigned_products)
        
        
def notassigned_productsControl(notassigned_products)
    deger = False
    for i in notassigned_productsList:
        if (i.getOrderNo() == notassigned_products.getOrderNo()):
            deger = True
            if (i.getItemNo() != notassigned_products.getItemNo()):
                deger = False
    if (deger == False):
        notassigned_productsList.append(notassigned_products)





for df in dataframe_order_list:
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for j in orderWarehouseMatch:
            if row['Item']== j.getItemNo():
                
                for k,v in dictBalance.items():
                    if (str(k[10:]) == str(j.getWarehouse())[1:]):
                        
                        if (int(row ['Qty/Ord']) <= int(dictBalance[str(j.getItemNo())+"/"+str(j.getWarehouse())])):
                            
                            assigned_products= AssignedRoutes( row['No.Ord.'], str(j.getItemNo()) ,row ['Qty/Ord'], str(j.getWarehouse()) )  
                            
                            routeListControl(assigned_products)
                       
                        elif (int(row ['Qty/Ord']) > int(dictBalance[str(j.getItemNo())+"/"+str(j.getWarehouse())])):
                            notassigned_products= NotAssignedProducts( row['No.Ord.'], str(j.getItemNo()) ,row ['Qty/Ord'], str(j.getWarehouse()) )
                            notassigned_productsControl(notassigned_products)```
````

Answer (score -1):

Given a list of objects, you could remove any similar objects by comparing their values.

```
l = [
    {'a':1},
    {'b':2},
    {'a':1}
]

nl = []
for thing in l:
    if thing not in nl:
        nl.append(thing)
```

Comment: I tried to use set() function but it is not working.